# Reduced density operators of a pure Bipartite state?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation

In (Bellucci, 2010; pg89) it is said (my wording):

> A pure bipartite state is separable if and only if the two reduced density matrices are pure.

Proving the "only if" part is easy but I am struggling to get anywhere with the "if" part. I.e. how do we prove that if $\rho_A$ and $\rho_B$ are pure then $\rho_{AB}$ is separable?  (Where here $\rho_A$ and $\rho_B$ are the corresponding reduced density matrices of $\rho_{AB}$.)

Intuitively it is obvious that this should be the case - but I am looking for a mathematical proof.

Comment: Is this maybe just an application of the [Schmidt decomposition of states](https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/bipartite-states-and-schmidt-decomposition)?

Comment: @FrederikvomEnde Opps for some reason I thought Schmidt decomposition assumed separability - clearly it doesn't - hence my question can clearly be answered via this. Feel free to put this as an answer and I will accept it.